# Contador con PHP+ $_SESSION

Tags: php, variables, session

Espero alguien me pueda apoyar en indicarme que estoy haciendo mal.

Estoy creando un contador con variables de session, todo anda bien cuando es la primera ves que se genera el contador, en la misma condición tengo que al llegar al día 1 de cualquier mes ese contador deberá resetearse y comenzar nuevamente con el contador en 1, por ahora no he podido lograr que funcione ya que al llegar al día indicado se queda el contador en 1 y ya no avanza.

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();


date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
$dia = date("d");

if (empty($_SESSION["contador"])) {

    $_SESSION["contador"] = 0;

} else if ($dia == 1) {

    $_SESSION["contador"] = 0;
}

$_SESSION["contador"]++;

echo "Contador: " . $_SESSION["contador"] . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: Creo que tienes los conceptos un poco mal. Segun entiendo quiere una variable de sesion donde se almacene el numero de dia  y cuando sea  el primer dia del me  dicha variable se resetee a  `1`  .    `Primero` :  las variables de sesion se borran al cerrar el navegador.  es decir que el usuario tendria que estar  entre `30` y `31` dias conectado. `Segundo`   los dias del mes ya son un contador.

Comment: ¿Para qué querrías algo así? ¿Por qué con variables de sesión?

Comment: Se me hizo una opción el trabajarlo con variables de session pero veo que no es la forma muy correcta para generar un contador, ¿hay alguna otra forma de trabajarlo pero que sea con php?

Comment: Sí, claro, hay muchas formas de persistencia... ¿Qué necesitas contar?

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo David, solo necesito un contador en php que cuando llegue a día uno se formateé y vuelva a 1, está variable la imprimo en tickets por eso necesito ese contador para que genere como un corte de mes.

Comment: Intenta guardarlo en Cookies, estas no se borran al cerrarse el navegador, pero si tienen una fecha de caducidad la cual puedes especificar.

Comment: @Nancy ¿Y dónde guardas esos tickets que vas numerando? ¿En una base de datos? ¿Tienes un campo para ese número?